# Selecting maximum value and inserting 0 if there are no entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions, coalesce

I have two tables, `items` and `bids`.

```
create table items (
    id serial primary key,
    store_id int,
    min_bid int
);

create table bids (
    item_id int,
    amount int
);
```

I want to select items and include information about the max bid.

```
select items.*, max(bids.amount) from items
    join bids on bids.item_id = items.id
where items.store_id = $store_id
group by items.id
```

However, when there are no bids for a particular item, the item just doesn't get selected. How can I make it so that when there are no bids, the item still gets selected and fills in the `max(bids.amount)` column with `items.min_bid`? (Or 0 is fine, too.)

I tried this:

```
select items.*, coalesce(max(bids.amount), items.min_bid) from items
    join bids on bids.item_id = items.id
where items.store_id = $store_id
group by items.id
```

which doesn't work. I'm assuming it's because of the join that the items aren't getting selected in the first place.

What should I do?

Comment: Aside from the issue of displaying the row, are you sure that you want to display 0 or a min_bid value? A bid of zero would be a different thing to no bid, and arguably a null would be better fit the situation.

Answer (score 2):

The two crucial elements are [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) and [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

- [@Adrian already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407769/selecting-maximum-value-and-inserting-0-if-there-are-no-entries#comment25277708_17407780) on `LEFT [OUTER ]JOIN`. It preserves all rows at the left hand of the join and fills missing columns to the right with NULL values. [The manual has more on the basics.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)
- [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) replaces NULL values with the provided alternative - `0` in this case.

```
SELECT i.*, COALESCE(max(b.amount), 0)
FROM   items i
LEFT   JOIN bids b ON b.item_id = i.id
WHERE  i.store_id = $store_id
GROUP  BY i.id
```

This alternative form is often faster when large parts of the sub-table are used: Aggregate in a subquery first, join later. This way you don't need an aggregation in the outer query. The second query also demonstrates how you can supply `items.min_bid` as replacement for NULL values.

```
SELECT i.*, COALESCE(b.max_amount, i.min_bid)
FROM   items i
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT item_id, max(amount) AS max_amount
   FROM   bids 
   ) b ON b.item_id = i.id
WHERE    i.store_id = $store_id;
```

Comment: +1, but I'd advise that it's not *always* faster to aggregate in a subquery and joining later. With large enough numbers of rows, I've found it to actually be frequently slower than aggregating in the outer query. (I'm suspecting this might the case here, if op has a join on large sets.) So test both approaches.

Comment: @Denis: Good point. The second query is only a good candidate if you aggregate large parts of the `bids` table. I amended the explanation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, to display the items with no bids, you have to make use of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select items.*, max(bids.amount) 
from items
left join bids on bids.item_id = items.id
where items.store_id = $store_id
group by items.id
```

Comment: Can you please explain the difference?

Comment: An inner join brings results present in both side of join, so items with no bids do not come over. Left join brings all from left and then corresponding from right side of join. Please refer to the best explanation on joins I've seen so far: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html